# REST Export View Path is empty

Tags: 8

I have created a REST export view of contents.

I have all default configuration. I set my path to "/api".

Now when I try to add another rest export view on it, and create a contextual filter and I want to provide the path into "api/%", I am getting "Path is empty" when I click apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is outdated. Should be fix by having proper configuration.